# How can I clone an object and set every properties value to null?

Tags: javascript, object, clone

As per title, I need to clone an object in Javascript like that below and set each values to zero. Of course the object properties can change.

```
  { _id: { action: null, date: null },
    avg: null,
    min: null,
    max: null,
    total: null }
```

Comment: do you mean to loop through every available property and set it to null?

Comment: Instructions unclear

Comment: You must mean every *known* property, not *unknown* because setting infinite number of properties to null could make your CPU explode.

Comment: Yes exactly what atmd said

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I can't believe that this is the best approach to whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to add missing rows to a time series dataset, for example if I ask for the values between 20 January and 27 January but I have rows only for a couple of those days, I need to add the missing ones with values set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// helper method to get the correct object type
function toType(x) {
  return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

// recursive function that sets all properties to null
// except objects which it passes back into the reset function
function reset(obj) {

  // clone the object
  var out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  for (var p in out) {
    if (toType(out[p]) === 'object') {
      reset(out[p]);
    } else {
      out[p] = null;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

reset(obj);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/75pvbtog/1/)